# Restrict single attribute usage in sequence using XML Schema

Tags: xml, xsd

Supposing the following instance document:

```
<person>
  <name>Maurice Moss</name>
  <addresses>
    <address current="true">441 Wallaby way</address>
    <address>2 Mercer Road</address>
  </addresses>
</person>
```

Using XML Schema, is it possible to enforce that only one `<address>` element can have it's `current` attribute set to "true" within the sequence.

Cheers

NOTE: I'm not quite sure how to phrase this problem, so I hope anyone having better idea can fix the title or place relevant tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think using XSD 1.0 you can enforce that there is only one element with a "current" attribute, as RichardTowers shows, but you cannot allow multiple "current" attributes of which only one may be true.

You can do this of course in XSD 1.1 using assertions:

```
<xs:assert test="count(address[@current='true']) eq 1"/>
```

(or `count(...) le 1` if that's what was intended).

Comment: Interesting, but a quick search tells me that `<assert>` is yet to be part of standard. If that's true, then will the above validates? To be honest, I'm still lacking experience in using schema to model information. EDIT: further search answers my question :) thanks.

Comment: My answer actually asserts that every `current` attribute has a unique value. Assuming current is an `xs:boolean` this allows at most 2 current attributes: one `"true"` and one `"false"`. Your answer is a much better solution if you have XSD 1.1.

Comment: @RichardTowers I'm not putting your alternative off the table, it is still simpler for me as I'm not yet comfortable with selectors/xpath/xquery. If I can upvote answers I would do for both (if not for elegance least for the full schema you put there).

Answer (score 0):

At least partly possible using `<xsd:unique/>`:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
    <xs:element name="person">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:all>
                <xs:element name="name"/>
                <xs:element name="addresses">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element name="address" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                                <xs:complexType>
                                    <xs:simpleContent>
                                        <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                                            <xs:attribute name="current" type="xs:boolean"/>
                                        </xs:extension>
                                    </xs:simpleContent>
                                </xs:complexType>
                            </xs:element>
                        </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>
                    <!-- HERE -->
                    <xs:unique name="onlyOneCurrentAddress">
                        <xs:selector xpath="address"/>
                        <xs:field xpath="@current"/>
                    </xs:unique>
                    <!-- /HERE -->
                </xs:element>
            </xs:all>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

This would prevent multiple `current="true"` attributes, but unfortuantely also multiple `current="false"`, so you may want to adapt it a bit.